# Trouble with hibernate's named query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, named-query

I am new to hibernate and I am having some trouble with the named query annotation. My code is as follows and is more or less generated by NetBeans

The BasicUser class:

```
    package wmc.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "basic_user")
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "BasicUser.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BasicUser b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BasicUser.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT b FROM BasicUser b WHERE b.firstName = :firstName"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BasicUser.findByLastName", query = "SELECT b FROM BasicUser b WHERE b.lastName = :lastName"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BasicUser.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM BasicUser b WHERE b.email = :email"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BasicUser.findByPassword", query = "SELECT b FROM BasicUser b WHERE b.password = :password")})
    public class BasicUser implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "First_Name")
        private String firstName;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Last_Name")
        private String lastName;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Email")
        private String email;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "Password")
        private String password;
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "basicUser")
        private StatUser statUser;
        @JoinColumn(name = "Group_Name", referencedColumnName = "Group_Name")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private Groups groupName;

        public BasicUser() {
        }
...
```

And the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mysql.dinhost.net:3306/coffeedrinkers</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bla</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">bla</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is where i try using the query:

```
public static boolean userExists(String email, String password) {
        Session session = null;

          try{

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

            session =sessionFactory.openSession();

            Object object = session.getNamedQuery("wmc.model.BasicUser.findByEmail").
                    setString("email", email).uniqueResult();
            BasicUser user = (BasicUser) object;

            if(user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                return true;
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return false;

    }
```

As I understand it i do not have to make any mapping xml's as this information is in the annotations.

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance:)

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WMCPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>coffeee</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the sun-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_coffeedrinkers_AnAmuserPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="mysql.dinhost.net"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="coffeedrinkers"/>
        <property name="User" value="bla"/>
        <property name="Password" value="bla"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://mysql.dinhost.net:3306/coffeedrinkers"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" pool-name="mysql_coffeedrinkers_AnAmuserPool" jndi-name="coffeee"  object-type="user"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of you named query is really its `name`, don't prefix it when calling `getNamedQuery`

```
 BasicUser user = (BasicUser) session.getNamedQuery("BasicUser.findByEmail").
         setString("email", email).uniqueResult();
```

By the way, since you're using JPA annotations, you should favor the JPA API over Hibernate API (i.e. JPA's `EntityManager` over Hibernate's `Session`).

Comment: Now I've done what you said and used EntityManager instead of Session. Now I get the following error:
08-07-2010 16:49:25 org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider configure
SEVERE: Could not find datasource: coffeee
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: @AnAmuser: Are you running this code inside GlassFish? If you're not, I guess you need to provide a `jndi.properties` file with the appropriate parameters, see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759300/how-to-set-up-jndi-properties-for-datastore/2759542#2759542). But that's a very different question that I can't cover in the comment box. If you are, the initial factory should be set. But as I said, this is really a different problem. You should open a new question for the sake of clarity (one question = one problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering on ways of how to setup JPA's EntityManager, see this:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf"/>

     <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                    p:showSql="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.books.web.entities"></property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
         <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
       </property>
   </bean> 

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    </bean>
```

After having your beans, you can optionally use annotation to get the JPATransactionManager and use that to get the EntityManagerFactory and use the factory to get your EntityManager and then you can create your query/named query..etc

Somewhere on top of your class member attributes, autowire the transactionManager using the following:

```
    @Autowired
    private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

public List<Book> findBookByCategory(String category){
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = transactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Book> result = entityManager.createNamedQuery( "Book.findByCategory", Book.class )
                                .setParameter("category", category)
                                .getResultList();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        return result;
    }
```

The beans on top of this post refer to some properties that are in a property file, so make sure you have hibernate.properites file with values like below:

```
hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto update
hibernate.generate_statistics true
hibernate.connection.driver_class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foobardb?useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
hibernate.connection.username put_user_name_here
hibernate.connection.password put_password_here
hibernate.connection.CharSet utf8
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding utf8
hibernate.connection.useUnicode true
```

For the beans to be successfully created you need hibernate-jpa jars, and you might also need hibernate validator jar. If you are using maven to manage dependencies in your project use these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

<!--  JPA -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>

                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Hope this helps :)